# Number of total possible outcomes when calculating probablities in Yahtzee

Tags: probability

So we have five six sided dice and we want to calculate the probabilities of getting results such as four of a kind...ie 55553.

So we find the total number of ways of getting four of a kind and divide it by the total number of possible outcomes from rolling 5 dice.

The number of total possible outcomes is $6^5$. ie..6 outcomes for each dice. But this is saying that a result of, say, 12345 is different from 54321. They are both getting counted as unique outcomes when we use $6^5$...yet they are the same result...So why do all the probability guides for Yahtzee say we use $6^5$ for the number of possible outcomes when that means we count many equivalent combinations as separate outcomes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imagine the dice as being tossed one at a time, or imagine them different-coloured. Then there are, as you point out, $6^5$ outcomes. They are all **equally likely**.

So for example the outcome $66666$ is just as likely as the outcome $12345$, which in turn is just as likely as $54321$.

But for the game, the order does not matter. Thus a reaasonable-sounding  way to list the outcomes is just to list the results on the dice, say in non-decreasing order. Thus $12345$ is one outcome, and $22346$ is another, and $16666$ still another. But we do not list $66166$, since that's the "same" outcome as $16666$.

**In principle**, that's fine, we can define as we wish what we mean by outcome. The **big** problem is that if we do not consider order, then not all outcomes are equally likely.  For example, five $1$'s is substantially less likely than getting a pattern of $5$ numbers that consists of the numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $5$.  Indeed, the latter is $120$ times as likely as the former.

Thus if we use **sequences** as outcomes, or equivalently consider the dice to be of different colours, we get that all outcomes are equally likely, and we can obtain other probabilities by simply **counting**.

If we decide instead to not distinguish between the dice, then all outcomes are no longer equally likely, and computing probabilities gets more complicated. That's why Yahtzee books recommend using the $6^5$-element sample space. We can indeed work with a smaller sample space, but then analysis of probabilities becomes more difficult.

Using the $6^5$-element sample space, we can see fairly easily that four $6$'s and a $3$ can happen in $5$ of our $6^5$ equally likely outcomes, so has probability $\dfrac{5}{6^5}$. And we can see that getting the numbers $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$, and $5$ showing on our dice happens in $5!=120$ of our outcomes, so has probability $\dfrac{120}{6^5}$.

Comment: I keep getting $6 \cdot \binom{5}{4}(\frac{1}{6})^4(1-\frac{1}{6})=\frac{5^2}{6^4}$. Whaere did I make a mistake?

Comment: If you are computing the probability of $4$ of a kind, the expressions you gave in the comment above are perfectly correct. You used a procedure somewhat different from pure counting, namely adding binomial probabilities. But the two procedures are equivalent.