# Better explanation on the need to count permutations to find probability

Tags: probability-theory, soft-question, education

A probability of an event can be computed as the ratio between the amount of outcomes which are part of the event and the total outcomes in the sample space. (Given a sample space which has the same probability for each outcome).

But, in this approach, when outcomes are subsets of a set (as in rolling k dices),  one needs to count outcomes by using permutations (not combinations).

How can I better explain this to students ? Most people are tempted to use combinations if nothing is said about order.

An example of the confusion (poorly answered, in my opinion): [Different probabilities with permutation and combination?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1676906/different-probabilities-with-permutation-and-combination))

Some fragments of the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/219925/number-of-total-possible-outcomes-when-calculating-probablities-in-yahtzee) are my favorite so far, the relevant phrases are:

> Imagine the dice as being tossed one at a time, or imagine them
> different-coloured

and

> The big problem is that if we do not consider order, then not all outcomes are equally likely. For example, five 1's is substantially less likely than getting a pattern of 5 numbers that consists of the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5. Indeed, the latter is 120 times as likely as the former.
>
> Thus if we use sequences as outcomes, or equivalently consider the dice to be of different colours, we get that all outcomes are equally likely, and we can obtain other probabilities by simply counting.

Comment: It is rather hard to follow you from the point where you say "one needs to count outcomes by using permutations (not combinations)." Opposing  permutations and combinations ?

Comment: I'm now fullfilled with the explanation given in the linked answer, but just to clear any fundamental misunderstanding of mine, could you care to comment on ? I don't understand what you are implying, when it comes to counting, counting combinations is different than counting permutations (even if you can connect the two concepts easily)

Comment: I begin to understand your point. But why don't you say that it's about the refinement of a non-elementary event into elementary events in order to be able to compute its probability ? Yes, for explaining by coloring dices, this is a rather classical pedagogical trick...

Comment: I see your point. It makes me see more clearly that the point where one has to pay attention is how you refine the event (and central to the explanation, because you can do it using combinations, it just changes how one assigns the likelihood of the "elementary" outcome). Thanks!